# How can I make a template output its own filename?

Tags: templating, variable

Is it possible to output the template name being used? Using a global variable or something similar? I am wanting to check which template is being used in a conditional.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but can you give an example why you want to check the template-name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This applies to Craft 2. For Craft 3+, see [hashchange's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/27606/4748).

---

You can get the current template’s name like so:

```
{{ _self.getTemplateName() }}
```

Comment: Careful with this; it returns an object of type `Twig_Markup`, which is then casted to a string. If you need template name strictly as a string, use `_self.getTemplateName().__toString`

Answer (score 10):

In Craft 3, `{{ _self.getTemplateName() }}` throws an error, but `{{ _self }}` does the trick.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe this is currently possible outside of the context of a Craft plugin.  Inside of a plugin, you could probably do it through a Twig extension so that you have access to the template instance, where you could call $template->getTemplateName(), which is part of Twig's Twig_Template abstract class.

Comment: Thanks Brad, would you consider adding a tag for it a some point?

Comment: I don't see why not!

Answer (score 3):

Post marked as answer doesn't work for me nowadays.
For me works:

```
{{ craft.app.requestedParams.template }}
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me too (Craft 4).