# How can I print the name of every template being rendered in HTML comments, when in devMode?

Tags: plugins, debugging

Is there a plugin or setting that prints the name of every template being rendered in HTML comments? I noticed this type of feature in a Drupal project and it was useful for debugging.

This is useful if you add it to every template you make, but I'd like to be able to turn it on/off globally for all templates in dev mode:
[How can I make a template output its own filename?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/449/how-can-i-make-a-template-output-its-own-filename)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So this sounded like a fun problem to solve... so I wrote the [Template Comments](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-templatecomments) plugin that does what you want:

This free plugin adds a HTML comment to demarcate `{% block %}`s and each Twig template that is included or extended.

Comment: Wow that's awesome! Thank you! I'll try it out on my next project!

Comment: Lmk how it works for you. If you find any issues, file them on GitHub: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-templatecomments/issues

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "no". There is no config or existing plugin that adds the debugging information I want.

Comment: The answer is now "yes" (see above) :)